# Wordpress of the post url redirect?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I have set the `Permalinks` to  custom  `/%postname%/` . eg: a post id  is 2, its url is

```
 `mysite.com/test.`
```

i want to  when the user access    `mysite.com/?p=2` it redirect to `mysite.com/test`

how do i do? or is there a pludgin to get that  thank u.

Comment: **Note to mods**: this question, if deemed constructive, would be a better fit for WPSE.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any plugin for that since it is the default behavior, except if you are using a very old version of worpdress.

Comment: the version is WordPress 3.2.1

Comment: i tested when i access mysite.com/?p=the post id. it can access the post and didn't make a redirect

Comment: Did you really set permalinks ?

Comment: Also: verify that your `.htaccess` file is WordPress-writeable. Does `mysite.com/test` render, or does it return a 404? If it returns a 404, then WordPress probably is unable to write to your `.htaccess`, preventing it from performing the redirect and displaying the pretty permalink.

Answer (score 0):

a little bit of googling:

```
http://yoast.com/wordpress/permalink-redirect/
```

Quote from the page:

> That way, a URL like this:
>
> ```
> http://www.example.com/page1/?q=ek
> ```
>
> Will be automatically redirected to:
>
> ```
> http://www.example.com/page1/
> ```